# Which variable has the biggest impact on ranking data

Tags: statistics

I've got a question on the most appropriate ways to analyze my data, and I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions or materials they wouldn't mind sharing.

I've got a dataset with a couple different categorical variables and then an importance ranking for some factors.

My questions is: What techniques should I apply to identify which of my categorical variables has the biggest impact on the order of importance of different factors?

I was thinking a hierarchical clustering on the categorical variables might let me use the dendrogram to identify which factors are most differentiating but the more I think about that the less convinced I am.

Any help at all on this would be massively appreciated!

Unfortunately I cant share my exact data but a hypothetical example looks like the below...

C = Categorical variables

R = Ranking of importance for each factor (1 being most important - 4 being least important)

| C1 Meal type | C2 Who with | C3 Time of day | R1 Taste | R2 Cost | R3 Convenience | R4 Novelty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Home made | Date | Evening | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Home made | Date | Lunch | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Home made | Flat mate | Evening | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| Home made | Flat mate | Lunch | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| Take out | Flat mate | Evening | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Take out | Flat mate | Lunch | 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| Take out | Date | Evening | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Take out | Date | Lunch | 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: Please also share an example of ranking or an ordering you have in mind.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified the codes:  The scores of importance come under the R variables and my categorical variables are coded C. I've updated the question too :). Hopefully all clear?

C = Categorical variables

R = Ranking of importance for each factor (1 being most important - 4 being least important)

Comment: One idea, since your categorical variables are boolean, you could calculate the average importance of a factor given a categorical variable is 0, then if it is 1 and look at the absolute difference. For example, for R1, variables C1 and C2 result in a 0 difference whereas for C3 the result is non zero, indicating that it has a larger impact on the average importance.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks for the suggestion. I'll implement and let you know how it looks!